# python pygame (scroll camera with player)

Tags: pygame

I am using pygame framework to implement my game in Python. Below is my code.

I do not know how to properly ask questions at StackOverflow, so I have included the whole program so that you can see all the details.

I would like to have a camera that would follow my player, but I do not know how to do that.

Could you, please, help me?

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Oyun():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 20
        pygame.display.set_caption("Cabbar_Oyunda_Vol01")
        self.uzunluk = 1280
        self.genişlik = 800
        self.pencere = pygame.display.set_mode((self.uzunluk, self.genişlik))
        self.area = self.uzunluk * self.genişlik
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.adam = pygame.image.load("R8E.png")
        self.bg = pygame.image.load("mountains.png").convert()
        self.bgWidth, self.bgHeight = self.bg.get_rect().size
        self.stageWidth = self.bgWidth * 2
        self.stagePosX=0
        self.startScrollingPosX=self.uzunluk/2
        self.circleRadius=25
        self.circlePosX=self.circleRadius
        self.playerPosX = self.circleRadius
        self.playerPosY = 685
        self.playerVelocityX = 0
        self.right = False
        self.left = False
        self.walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load("L3.png"), pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'), pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
        self.walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'),pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
        self.walkCount=0
        self.canavar_left=[pygame.image.load("L1E.png"),pygame.image.load("L2E.png"),pygame.image.load("L3E.png"),pygame.image.load("L4E.png"),pygame.image.load("L5E.png"),pygame.image.load("L6E.png"),pygame.image.load("L7E.png"),pygame.image.load("L8E.png"),pygame.image.load("L9E.png")]
        self.canavar_right = [pygame.image.load("R1E.png"),  pygame.image.load("R2E.png"), pygame.image.load("R3E.png"),pygame.image.load("R4E.png"), pygame.image.load("R5E.png"), pygame.image.load("R6E.png"),pygame.image.load("R7E.png"), pygame.image.load("R8E.png"), pygame.image.load("R9E.png")]
        self.c_walkount=0
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.sayac=0
        self.yorgunluk_x=70
        self.font=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",17)
        self.mermi=pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
        self.mermi_x=0
        self.mermi_y=0
        self.mermi_stage="ready"
        self.deneme=pygame.image.load("bg.jpg")
        self.a = self.stagePosX + 1300
        self.canavar=False
        pygame.mixer.music.load("background.wav")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
        self.yon=1
        self.scroll=[0,0]

    def move(self):
        self.clock.tick(40)
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkCount = 0
        if self.right:
            self.pencere.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.circlePosX, self.playerPosY))
            self.walkCount += 1

        elif self.left:
            self.pencere.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.circlePosX, self.playerPosY))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            self.pencere.blit(self.walkRight[0], (self.circlePosX, self.playerPosY))
        if self.canavar:
            if self.a>1400 or self.a<1200:
                self.yon*=-1
            self.a += 2 * self.yon

    def fire_bullet(self,circlePosX,playerPosY):
        self.mermi_stage="fire"
        self.pencere.blit(self.mermi,(circlePosX+40,playerPosY+20))

    def kontrol(self):
        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if self.mermi_stage is "ready":
                self.mermi_x=self.circlePosX
                self.mermi_y=self.playerPosY
                self.fire_bullet(self.mermi_x,self.mermi_y)
                self.mermi_ses = pygame.mixer.Sound("laser.wav")
                self.mermi_ses.play()

        if self.mermi_stage is "fire":
            self.fire_bullet(self.mermi_x,self.mermi_y)
            self.mermi_x+=18
        if self.mermi_x>=1280:
            self.mermi_x=self.circlePosX
            self.mermi_stage="ready"

        self.pencere.blit(self.adam, (self.a, 685))

    def Game(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return "son"
        self.pencere.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.left = False
            self.right = True
            self.circlePosX += 5

        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.left = True
            self.right = False
            self.circlePosX=-5


        if not (self.isJump):
            if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.isJump = True
                self.left = False
                self.right = True
                self.walkCount = 0
                self.sayac += 1
        else:
            if self.jumpCount >= -10:
                self.playerPosY -= (self.jumpCount * abs(self.jumpCount)) * 0.5
                self.jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                self.jumpCount = 10
                self.isJump = False
        self.canavar=True
        self.move()
        self.kontrol()
        pygame.display.update()

Game = Oyun()
while True:
    Durum = Game.Game()
    if Durum == "son":
        break
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I assume you are saying that you have a player you want to control and move through a game environment, but from the display perspective you want the player stationary and the background and environment to shift under the player instead. Like the game was being displayed by a camera looking down from above the players head (or from the side in a side-view). One way could be that instead of adjusting the players position you just move everything else. Another could be to adjust everything's position as normal, but when doing the displaying it is all offset relative to the player before display.

Comment: ı want do a game like mario, how can ı do screen scrolling with player , please if you know write code :)  because ı cant did

Answer (score 0):

A simple(but not most efficient) way to do this would be to move the background and all other assets, while keeping the player stationary.

```py
# insert code in each object in background/assets
if right:
    OBJECT.right()  # code to change location
if left:
    OBJECT.left()  #code to change location
```

Also, off-topic, but it is easier to have a single direction variable with -1 for left, 0 for stationary, and 1 for right. You can also easily add speed to this, too, so keep this in mind and implement it if you can.